# Can C# do something like SPI in Java (Meta-inf/service)?

Tags: c#, java, ikvm

I am currently working on converting `.JPEG` file to `.WSQ` file, I have successfully done it in Java using a library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmrtd/.

Now I wanted to do the same thing in C#, I converted the `.jar` files into `.dll` files using IKVM and I can call the libraries of Java in my C# application. But there is a problem, in Java, I found out that the function to convert JPEG to WSQ is available in the external library which is added as an external SPI from the META-INF/service folder. Something like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html.

The external library is called "indirectly" in Java from what I understand, how can I do this in C#? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "external library" a second jar file then compile both jar files in one step with the parenthesis syntax. Then it should work.

For details see the IKVM wiki:

- [Convert a jar file to a dll and use it as library](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Convert_a_jar_file_to_a_dll_and_use_it_as_library)
- [ClassLoader](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader)

Comment: hi @Horcrux7, my external library is wsq_imageio.jar, it is an new SPI for the base java library javax.imageio.. 
IKVM has its own .dll for base java library, I tried to merge the wsq_imageio.jar with IKVM.OpenJDK.Media.dll using

'ikvmc.exe -target:library wsq_imageio.jar -reference:IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll -reference:IKVM.
OpenJDK.SwingAWT.dll  -reference:IKVM.OpenJDK.Media.dll'

but the output is still the same

Comment: Ask your question on the mailing list from IKVM. What you want should work but I does not know what you do wrong.

Comment: @Horcusx7 - I know it should work but I just don't know which part I did it wrong, anyway, I somehow managed to get what I wanted using another library. Thanks for the reply =)